# ofstream not printing despite being open

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

I am trying to print data to a file; however, the file that is created is empty, and nothing seems to be printed to it.  I know that the file stream is open and good because my cout statements are printing what i am expecting, but for some reason, the write-file is blank when I check.  Any solutions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
void printToStream(std::ofstream &fileStream, std::string printString) {
    if (fileStream.is_open() && fileStream.good()) {
        std::cout << "printing to file " << std::endl;
        std::cout << printString;
        fileStream << std::flush;
        fileStream << printString;
    } else {
        printError("File not open");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you're calling this function.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f702b9ff4b09ee3). It's entirely possible I fixed the problem in the course of adding code to what you show.

Comment: @rustyx moving the flush to the end, fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @rustyx if you post answer in answer section, ill accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `std::flush` to the end of the output.

For example like this:

```
    fileStream << printString << std::flush;
```